# Run Program as Administrator from SSH in Windows

Tags: powershell, ssh, cmd, administrator

I created a SSH Server on Windows 10 (Open SSH) and I'm connecting to it via my Phone with an app called Jucy SSH - it's secured with PKI and Passphrase. I log in with my "regular" user name.

Now what I want is to be able to launch a specific Program with elevated rights. I cannot launch it when navigating to said program.

In a regular cmd session I can launch the program using `"C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"` I can also run it with elevated rights using `runas /user:Administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"` It asks for a password but after entering it the program doesn't launch, in fact nothing happens.
Which is weird because I can launch notepad.exe from the ssh session.

and I can launch it from my PC with this powershell script:

```
function Start-ProcessAsAdministrator {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$FilePath,
        [string]$Arguments = ""
    )

    $psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $psi.FileName = $FilePath
    $psi.Arguments = $Arguments
    $psi.Verb = "runas"

    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $psi

    try {
        $process.Start() | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to start process with admin rights: $_"
    }
}

# Now, use the function to start your program with admin rights
$programPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\program.exe"
Start-ProcessAsAdministrator -FilePath $programPath
```

I can launch a Powershell session using `powershell` but I cannot execute the script due to a security violation.

What do I have to do to be able to launch a program with elevated rights using a Windows SSH session?

Comment: I just noticed that the Task starts, it is visible in Task Manager but it does not launch the GUI of the app. I have tried to use PSTools to do it, but it also doesn't work, there's an error - `The app closed unexpectedly`

Comment: Start PS by right click on PS shortcut and select Run As Admin.  Probably failing because you are not run As Admin.  PS doesn't run As Admin unless you select from shortcut.

Comment: @jdweng Now how exactly would I realize a right click in a SSH Powershell session from a Terminal?

Comment: To run PowerShell as administrator from cmd, Open the command prompt, type PowerShell, and then enter “Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs”. This will open a new PowerShell window with administrator privileges.

Comment: You should be able to execute a script if you run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force` first

Comment: @NicoNekoru Thanks. and Yes, now it works, I'm not getting a error message, however, on the remote machine, the process starts, but the gui does not open. I need the GUI to open ( this is so I can launch connect via steam link, which does not work if the gui does not launch with the process.)

Comment: you need to run it as system for it to open across sessions, otherwise you have to run it under their context. Perhaps a task scheduler?